# get query value from url VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core

I'm new vuejs learner and I want to get the query value from url to use it in the vue method as explained below.

This is the route:

```
{
    path: "/FetchData/:query?",
    name: "FetchData",
    component: FetchData,
}
```

And this is the link to redirect to the second page

```
   <router-link :to="{ path: '/FetchData', query: { query: country.countryName }}">
```

this is the api

```
 public IActionResult GetSubs(string query, int? subs)
    {
        return Ok(SubService.GetSubs(query, subsId));
    }
```

This is the vue method calling the api

```
getSubs() {
            axios.get("https://localhost:44391/api/Subs/GetSubs")
                .then(res => this.subs = res.data)
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
```

And finally, this is the html to display data

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column ml-2"><span>{{subs.subsId}}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <h6 style="text-align:left">{{subs.label}}</h6>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using vuejs 2 you can access query using: `this.$route.query` 
but if you're using v3 it should be something like:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()

    return {
       query: computed( () => route.query )
    }
  }
}
```

then you can use `this.query` inside your method